# how to tell jsf which packages store managed beans

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a web application which uses JSF 2.0 mojjarra. i want to put my managed bean classes to a package named like this.

```
package com.myapp.managedbean
```

How can i tell the jsf to scan this package for annotated managed beans.

My maven dependencies

```
dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
    <version>3.4</version>  
</dependency>

<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>  
    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>  
    <version>7.0.26</version>  
    <scope>provided</scope>  
  </dependency>
```

My managed bean :

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

```
@ManagedBean(name="helloWorld")
@SessionScoped
public class HelloWorld{

    @ManagedProperty(value="Hello World")
    private String a;

public String getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
}
```

}

And my page :

```
<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>

<p:outputLabel for="extended"  />  
            <p:inputText id="extended" value="#{helloWorld.a}" />

</h:body>

</html>
```

The page only shows an empty text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify just place the annotations above your class name , like this
It will find them by itself...

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {
```

instead of

```
@ManagedProperty(value="Hello World")
private String a;
```

just do

```
private String a = "Hello World";
```

this is not how `ManagedProperty` are used, do some google about it

in general `ManagedProperty` are for injecting values / beans

here an example how to inject another bean

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{someOtherBean }")
private SomeOtherBean someOtherBean ; // + getter and setter
```

Comment: Really, i was wrong then. Therefore, it is not work because of other configurations. Thank you. i will focus another issues.

Comment: however, it does not work. i am using primefaces. primefaces tags works on the page perfectly. however it does not show the managed bean values. any idea for this problem ?

Comment: have you included jsf api/impl jars? are you using the right imports? `import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; `import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;` do you see any errors in server / browser ?

Comment: Yes. i use these annotations. i use jsf-api-2.0.2.jar and jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar . There is no error in the console. i use tomcat 7 and servlet 3.0.1. i really go crazy.

Comment: ohh really sorry. my fault. i used wrong managed bean name. i solve the issue. thank you.